# How to generate a sequence order number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence

I have the following data:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| IDTRX  | IDCUST | ITEM   | IDORDER| ORDERSEQ |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|1       |  A     |  SHOES | C18001 |          |
|2       |  A     |  BAG   | C18001 |          |
|3       |  A     |  TV    | C18005 |          | 
|4       |  A     |  IPHONE| C18008 |          |
|5       |  B     |  BAG   | C18002 |          | 
|6       |  B     |  TV    | C18003 |          |
|7       |  C     |  IPHONE| C18006 |          |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

I want to know how many times CUSTOMER items order
how to query to fill the order sequence (ORDERSEQ column) grouped by IDCUST and IDORDER?

so the display of query results like this :

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| IDTRX  | IDCUST | ITEM   | IDORDER| ORDERSEQ |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|1       |  A     |  SHOES | C18001 | ORDER-1  |
|2       |  A     |  BAG   | C18001 | ORDER-1  |
|3       |  A     |  TV    | C18005 | ORDER-2  | 
|4       |  A     |  IPHONE| C18008 | ORDER-3  |
|5       |  B     |  BAG   | C18002 | ORDER-1  | 
|6       |  B     |  TV    | C18003 | ORDER-2  |
|7       |  C     |  IPHONE| C18006 | ORDER-1  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.idorder)
        from t t2
        where t2.idcust = t.idcust and t2.idtrx <= t.idtrx
       ) as orderseq
from t;
```

Note:  This does not format the value as a string.  I think an integer is more useful in any case (and formatting as a string is trivial).

In many cases, variables are a more efficient solution:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@oc = concat_ws(':', t.idcust, t.idorder), @rn,
                  if(@oc := concat_ws(':', t.idcust, t.idorder), 1, 1)
                    )
                 )
       ) as orderseq
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by t.idcust, t.idorder, t.idtrx
     ) t cross join
     (select @oc := '', @rn := 0) params;
```

EDIT:

You can update a column in the table using `join`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               (select count(distinct t2.idorder)
                from t t2
                where t2.idcust = t.idcust and t2.idtrx <= t.idtrx
               ) as new_orderseq
        from t
       ) tt
       on t.idtrx = tt.idtrx
    set orderseq = new_orderseq;  -- or whatever string formatting you want
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i mean is how to update the column orderseq?

Answer (score 0):

yesss, working well.

---

-- Table structure for t_orders

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_orders`;
CREATE TABLE `t_orders` (
  `IDTRX` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IDCUST` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ITEM` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDORDER` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORDERSEQ` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDTRX`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

-- Records of t_orders

---

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `t_orders` VALUES (1, 'A', 'SHOES', 'C18001', '');
INSERT INTO `t_orders` VALUES (2, 'A', 'BAG', 'C18001', '');
INSERT INTO `t_orders` VALUES (3, 'A', 'TV', 'C18005', '');
INSERT INTO `t_orders` VALUES (4, 'A', 'IPHONE', 'C18008', '');
INSERT INTO `t_orders` VALUES (5, 'B', 'BAG', 'C18002', '');
INSERT INTO `t_orders` VALUES (6, 'B', 'TV', 'C18003', '');
INSERT INTO `t_orders` VALUES (7, 'C', 'IPHONE', 'C18006', '');
COMMIT;

And this query solution for update ORDERSEQ column :

update t_orders a join
       (select t.*,
               (select CONCAT('ORDER-',count(distinct t2.IDORDER))
                from t_orders t2
                where t2.IDCUST = t.IDCUST and t2.IDTRX <= t.IDTRX
               ) as new_orderseq
        from t_orders t
       ) tt
     on a.IDTRX = tt.IDTRX set a.ORDERSEQ = new_orderseq;

thanks all

[image: screenshoot]